# Send HTML page from Form to User using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a webpage coded in HTML that I have added a form to. What I would like is for our employees to go to the URL of the webpage, fill out the form with the customer's name, address, email and appointment date and time, then for a complete copy of the webpage and form data to be sent to the email specified in the form. Essentially, our employees will be using the webpage/form to send appointment confirmations to our clients using email. Our clients will receive the coded HTML with form data in their email, confirming their appointment times. Would like to use PHP for the server-side processing of all this.

Thanks for all your help

```
<html>
<head>
<title>emailConfirm-Appointment</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (emailConfirm-Appointment.psd) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="612" height="792" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <img src="http://www.cfproroofing.com/email/images/emailConfirmAppt-header.jpg" alt="" width="612" height="165" border="0"></td>
    </tr>


  <tr>
        <td colspan="5" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <img src="http://www.cfproroofing.com/email/images/emailConfirmAppt-title.png" alt="" width="612" height="31" border="0"></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>

        <td height="130" colspan="3" valign="top">
        <fieldset align="right">
<!-- a helper script for vaidating the form-->
<script language="JavaScript" src="scripts/gen_validatorv31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<form method="POST" name="contactform" action="testForm-handler.php">

<label for='name'><span style="font-size:14px">Customer:</span></label> 
<input type="text" name="name"> <br>


<label for='email'><span style="font-size:14px">Email:</span></label>
<input type="text" name="email"> <br>


<label for='address'><span style="font-size:14px">Address:</span></label>
<input type="text" name="address"> <br>


<label for='city'><span style="font-size:14px">City:</span></label>
<input type="text" name="city"> <br>

<label for='date-time'><span style="font-size:14px">Date & Time:</span></label>
<input type="text" name="date-time"> <br>


<input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
</form>
</fieldset>

<script language="JavaScript">
// Code for validating the form
// Visit http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml
// for details
var frmvalidator  = new Validator("contactform");
frmvalidator.addValidation("name","req","Please provide your name"); 
frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req","Please provide your email"); 
frmvalidator.addValidation("email","email","Please enter a valid email address"); 
</script></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <img src="http://www.cfproroofing.com/email/images/emailConfirmAppt-body_Walter.jpg" alt="" width="612" height="237" border="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td width="102.5" height="44" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="102.5" height="44" alt=""></td>
        <td width="102.5" height="44" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="102.5" height="44" alt=""></td>

        <td width="203" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <a href="http://www.CFProRoofing.com" target="_blank">
                <img src="http://www.cfproroofing.com/email/images/emailConfirmAppt-buttonWebsite.png" width="203" height="44" border="0" alt=""></a></td>

            <td width="102.5" height="44" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="102.5" height="44" alt=""></td>
        <td width="102.5" height="44" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="102.5" height="44" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <img src="http://www.cfproroofing.com/email/images/emailConfirmAppt-signatureKalina.jpg" alt="" width="612" height="122" border="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <img src="http://www.cfproroofing.com/email/images/emailConfirmAppt-footer.png" alt="" width="612" height="83" border="0"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>

<?php 
$errors = '';
$sendTo = "test@plantosellfl.com";//<-----Put Your email address here.
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
   empty($_POST['email']) ||
   empty($_POST['address']) ||
   empty($_POST['city']) || 
   empty($_POST['date-time']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$address = $_POST['address']; 
$city = $_POST['city'];
$date_time = $_POST['date-time'];  

if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
    $to = $sendTo; 
    $email_subject = "Confirm Appointment: $address";

    $email_body ='<html>
            <head>
            <title>emailConfirm-Appointment</title>
            </head>

            <body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
            <table width="612px" height="792px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <img src="http://www.cfproroofing.com/email/images/emailConfirmAppt-header.jpg" alt="" width="612" height="165" border="0">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <img src="http://www.cfproroofing.com/email/images/emailConfirmAppt-title.png" alt="" width="612" height="31" border="0">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td height="130" colspan="3" valign="top" border="0">


                    <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
                    <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?><br>
                    <?php echo $_POST["address"]; ?><br>
                    <?php echo $_POST["city"]; ?><br>
                    <?php echo $_POST["date-time"]; ?><br>

                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <img src="http://www.cfproroofing.com/email/images/emailConfirmAppt-body_Walter.jpg" alt="" width="612" height="237" border="0">
                     </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td width="102.5" height="44" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <img src="http://www.cfproroofing.com/email/images/spacer.gif" width="102.5" height="44" alt="">
                    </td>
                    <td width="102.5" height="44" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <img src="http://www.cfproroofing.com/email/images/spacer.gif" width="102.5" height="44" alt="">
                    </td>
                    <td width="203" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <a href="http://www.CFProRoofing.com" target="_blank">
                            <img src="http://www.cfproroofing.com/email/images/emailConfirmAppt-buttonWebsite.png" width="203" height="44" border="0" alt=""></a>
                     </td>
                     <td width="102.5" height="44" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <img src="http://www.cfproroofing.com/email/images/spacer.gif" width="102.5" height="44" alt="">
                     </td>
                     <td width="102.5" height="44" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <img src="http://www.cfproroofing.com/email/images/spacer.gif" width="102.5" height="44" alt="">
                     </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <img src="http://www.cfproroofing.com/email/images/emailConfirmAppt-signatureKalina.jpg" alt="" width="612" height="122" border="0">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <img src="http://www.cfproroofing.com/email/images/emailConfirmAppt-footer.png" alt="" width="612" height="83" border="0">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
            </body>
            </html>
            ';

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";

    $headers .= 'From: <KaMendez@CFProRoofing.com>' . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: <KaMendez@CFProRoofing.com>' . "\r\n";



    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

} 


?>
```

Comment: Have you written contact-form-handler.php yet?

Comment: It's a generic template I was going to try to customize. I don't know how to get it to send a copy of the webpage to an email address we specify in the form.

Comment: The email address in the form will come to the PHP script as $_POST['email']. Sending the mail will depend on the available features of your server and PHP version. If you don't have any code for that in the "generic template" let me know and I will post a small example in an answer.

Comment: So, after some more research and a lot of troubleshooting, I've got the php file working and emailing. However, when the email is received the <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?> lines of code inside the html aren't working. I'll repost my coding here. Hopefully you can help.

Comment: Since you are bulding a string, try replacing it with `'.$_POST["name"].'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, when you build the `$email_body`, you want to insert the `$_POST` variables inside it.

You don't need to put the `<?php  $_POST["name"] ?>` tag inside it: it won't be interpreted as it is just part of the string. In fact php just suppose that you want to send a string with a less-than sign, then a question mark and so on.

If you want to put a viariable in your string try:

```
    $email_body ='<html>
                  ...
                  ... html stuff  ...
                  ...
                  <td height="130" colspan="3" valign="top" border="0">
                   ';
    $email_body .= $_POST["name"];
    $email_body .= $_POST["email"];
    $email_body .= $_POST["address"];

    $email_body .='</td>
                  ...
                  ... html stuff  again ...
                  ...
                   </html>';
```

In this way:

- First you set a string with some HTML code in `$email_body`. And this HTML string is inside single apex-s!
- Then you concatenate to it your variables (these are not inside apexs)
- Then you concatenate a string of HTML again.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your advice worked flawlessly!!

Comment: You can set this as "accepted answer" then! (click the "V" here in the left)